# SQL Syntax to Insert Dates and Times into a Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, sql-server-2008

In my project, I need to convert the following function, which creates a string to insert into a database, into the correct syntax for inserting a datetime datatype... Does anyone know a way I can do this?

```
Public Shared Function sqlString(str As String) As String

    Return "'" & str.Replace("'", "''") & "'"

End Function
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. Many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Comment: @jarlh Thanks, I've retagged. The DBMS we're inserting into is MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Use parameters. Use parameters. Use. Parameters.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer the entire program is paramaterised, this import procedure is only going to be used once, then it's redundant and being taken out, so for this we didn't bother with it

Comment: Database parameters will save you having to write additional parse functions and will natively deal with the apostrophe issue and date formats. "This import procedure is only going to be used once" for now, and then your app expands, and someone inherits sql injection issues.

Comment: It may also be worth looking at these "bulk" options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937.aspx

Comment: @AndrewMortimer This isn't going to be an app or a program that is used on mass, there is only going to be 4 people who use it and none of it is going online, so SQL injection won't be an issue like it would be with largely used apps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118534/discussion-between-andrew-mortimer-and-david).

Comment: SQL Parameters are about being able to write clear, readable code and avoid all sorts of things from escaping names (like `D'Artagnan`) to data type changes.as well as SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I stored the values as either a date or a time by calling the following functions respectively, during the INSERT statement

```
Public Shared Function sqlDate(dt As DateTime) As String

    If dt.Date = Nothing Then

        Return dt.ToString("")

    Else

        Return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

    End If

End Function

Public Shared Function sqlTime(dt As DateTime) As String

    Return dt.ToString("hhmmss")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

sql = "INSERT INTO tblModules(ModuleID, ModuleName, NumberUsers, License, Username, ContractID,datetime) VALUES(" & modID & ", " & sqlString(modname) & ", " & numusers & "," & sqlString(license) & ", " & sqlString(username) & ", " & contractID & ","&sqlDateTime(DateTime.Now)&")" 
try this

Comment: Hi, I don't want to add DateTime.Now, I need it to copy over the values from the database

Comment: declare a variable and use it instead of DateTime.Now